# Можно ли заливать venv на github?

Tags: python, git, github, pycharm

Работаю в PyCharm. Создаю проект, и ИДЕ сама создает для него отдельный интерпретатор по пути {project}/venv, куда и скачивает сам интерпретатор питона и библиотеки.

Когда я делаю коммит и заливаю на гитхаб, то происходит следующее - веточка, взятая (checkout) с гитхаба, ругается на невозможность запустить проект по причине отсутствия python.exe. Причем даже не там, куда ссылается конфигурация проекта ({project}/venv/Scripts/python.exe), а на путь до AppData\Local (почему он туда лезет, откуда он вообще взял этот путь?).

Вопрос не столько "как починить?", а "а так вообще можно делать?". То есть можно ли вообще добавлять venv в проект гита и коммитить его.
Ну и конечно же, как правильно выстроить архитектуру проекта.

Comment: `venv` коммитить нельзя, нужно коммитить зависимости (`requirements.txt`), чтобы тот кто склонит проект, мог создать свой венв и поставить туда зависимости

Comment: Содержимое venv завязано на особенности текущего компьютера, так что заливать его бессмысленно

Comment: Отметьте ответ как верный. если он вам помог.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Заливать venv на гит - бессмысленно
Для того, чтобы другой разработчик мог развернуть проект у себя на машине нужно

1. Активировать виртуальное окружение
2. ввести в терминале `pip freeze > requirements.txt` , что запишет все установленные библиотеки в txt файл.
3. Залить requirements.txt на гит.

Так же вам стоит почитать про gitignore (его можно создать вместе с проектом на гитхаб выбрав нужный язык.)

UPD: На счёт архитектуры - лично я создаю окружение на одном уровне с проектом. Т.е. в корне у меня лежат

```
-project_name
-venv
```

Думаю если что-то не так - меня поправят в комментариях
[image: Думаю если что-то не так - меня поправят в комментариях]

Comment: Я храню все в `~/.virtualenvs/`, но внутри проекта тоже популярный и валидный кейс.